# HTTP: 301-Permanently Moved redirects me to original address?

Tags: http

I'm using Telnet for the first time and am trying to simply connect to a certain webpage: http://net.cs.uni-bonn.de/de/wg/cs/lehre/ws-201415/sysprog. To do that, I've given the following input on the command line:

```
telnet net.cs.uni-bonn.de 80
```

Telnet connects successfully and I put in the following request:

```
GET /de/wg/cs/lehre/ws-201415/sysprog HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

Then, Telnet returns the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 13:37:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Location: http://net.cs.uni-bonn.de/de/wg/cs/lehre/ws-201415/sysprog
Cache-Control: max-age=360
Expires: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 13:43:06 GMT
Content-Length: 388
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://net.cs.uni-bonn.de/de/wg/cs/lehre/ws-201415/sysprog">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at <a href="mailto:webmaster-4@cs.uni-bonn.de">127.0.0.1</a> Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Any idea why I'm getting this 301 error? I'm really confused, because the new redirect address being given is the exact same as the address I've put in, and the address clearly has content when I open it in the web browser. I can open other websites with the same syntax, but I have to be able to call this website for my assignment, so I'd like to know why this error might be happening and how to get around it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   telnet net.cs.uni-bonn.de 80
> ```
>
> Telnet connects successfully and I put in the following request:
>
> ```
>   GET /de/wg/cs/lehre/ws-201415/sysprog HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 127.0.0.1
> ```

Telnet first resolves the domain name to an IP address, and uses the IP address to connect to the server. Many servers serve more than one domain name from the same IP, which is why you need to supply a meaningful `Host:`  header:

```
Host: net.cs.uni-bonn.de
```

Without this, the server has no idea which domain name the request is meant for.

In this particular case, the server obviously does know, but is redirecting you because your HTTP request was malformed.

Answer (score 0):

Due the limitation of IPv4 addresses, multiple hostnames can resolve to a single IP address. HTTP allows each hostname to have a different website without having to use different ports. You specify which hostname you want to request in the Host header.

You said:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

It is redirecting you from:

```
http://127.0.0.1/de/wg/cs/lehre/ws-201415/sysprog
```

to

```
http://net.cs.uni-bonn.de/de/wg/cs/lehre/ws-201415/sysprog
```